# CSS3 resize property allows only increasing DIV size

Tags: html, css, resize

There is a *resize* property in CSS3 which can be applied to a `div` (e.g. http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-resize/). I am building a rich UI, and found this feature very useful in my case. I try to rely on CSS3 more than JavaScript, so I like this "native" solution.

This **problem** is - it doesn't allow a user to make the box less than its original size.

It reproduces in Safari 5.0.5, Chrome 12.0.742.91, while Firefox 4.0.1 resizes a box in both ways.

**Question**: is there any workaround for desired behavior? I still want to stick with *resize* property.

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/wsCQm/

```
.resizable {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;    
     overflow: scroll;
     resize: both;   
}

<div class="resizable"> 
    Some stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is set by the browser

> The user agent may restrict the resizing range to something suitable, such as between the original formatted size of the element, and large enough to encompass all the element's contents.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize

Comment: At least some clarity from the spec. Now, I'm craving for some -webkit-* facility to change this "something suitable" to something meaningful.