# HTML5 resize only on makes items larger than original size, not smaller

Tags: html, css, webkit, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Google Chrome extension and need to have a particular `<div>` tag resizable. This works, but it can only be resized to be larger than its original size, not smaller.
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313358/css3-resize-property-allows-only-increasing-div-size), this is set by the browser.
Are there any workarounds that allow the div to be made smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is currently no way to use a CSS resize attribute without a fixed minimum width unless you explicitly set that width.

If you wanted to resize a DIV that is currently 200px to 100px in height, you have to set the styles height to 100px to force the resize attribute to start resizing from there.

Comment: I created the <div> myself.  The problem is that the <div> is created with a default width and height, and Chrome's implementation of resize does not allow you to resize below that

Comment: @chustar I apologize, I didn't read your question carefully, I updated my response. The only way for now is to set the width/height to your absolute minimum for the extension and resize CSS attribute from there.