# How to resize DIV to less than its initial width & height?

Tags: javascript, css, html, resize

I want to give the user the ability to resize a DIV to less than its declared width and height. How to ?

Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/hW4nn/

HTML

```
<div class="divClass"></div>
```

CSS

```
.divClass {
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery UI's Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the browser will not let you resize any smaller than the initial size. My workaround would be to set the initial CSS to a minimal width and height (whatever you think that should be, e.g. 50px or so); then use javascript to change the CSS of the div onload so that it is properly sized.

See also [HTML5 resize only on makes items larger than original size, not smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771650/html5-resize-only-on-makes-items-larger-than-original-size-not-smaller).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried it, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/WSkZP/ ... Unfortunately, it cannot be resized to less than the last width and height set values